# LINQ get only ONE if it is duplicated

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I have this list

Sender            Receiver

1 --------------- 2

2 --------------- 1

1 --------------- 3

1 --------------- 2

3 --------------- 1

2 --------------- 1

In this list i like only to get:

1 - 2 and 1 - 3

The others are duplicated, the Id in the right are same at the left, two id (sender and receiver) are pointing the same table, for me it is immaterial whether it is 1 -3 or 3-1, I like only get one of this. It is posible? Thanks!

Comment: Is Sender/Receiver pair an object? If so, create a IEqualityComparer type and pass an instance of it to `Distinct` and your golden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement equality on your class (or via an [`IEqualityComparer<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) like this, a simple [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will get you the results you want:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Sender { get; set; }
    public int Receiver { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Sender ^ Receiver;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other == null || this.GetType() != other.GetType())
            return false;
        var o = (MyClass)other;
        return Math.Min(this.Sender, this.Receiver) == Math.Min(o.Sender, o.Receiver) &&
            Math.Max(this.Sender, this.Receiver) == Math.Max(o.Sender, o.Receiver);
    }
}

// use like
var myList = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass { Sender = 1, Receiver = 2 },
    new MyClass { Sender = 2, Receiver = 1 },
    new MyClass { Sender = 1, Receiver = 3 },
    new MyClass { Sender = 1, Receiver = 2 },
    new MyClass { Sender = 3, Receiver = 1 },
    new MyClass { Sender = 2, Receiver = 1 },
};
var distinctOnes = myList.Distinct(); // contains 1,2 and 1,3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can just pick the smaller of the sender/receiver and call `Distinct`:

```
list.Select(l => new 
    {
        Sender   = l.Sender < l.Receiver ? l.Sender : l.Receiver,
        Receiver = l.Sender < l.Receiver ? l.Receiver : l.Sender
    })
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some good answers already, but i already had this ready so here is another LINQ solution

```
        var recieverHighArr = from e in list
                      where e.Sender < e.Reciever
                      select new { high = e.Reciever, low = e.Sender };

        var senderHighArr= from e in list
                      where e.Sender >= e.Reciever
                      select new { high = e.Sender, low = e.Reciever };

        var concat = senderHighArr.Concat(recieverHighArr).Distinct();

        foreach (var ob in concat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ob.high + " " + ob.low);
        }
```